# Error in configuring MySql workbench - Failed to connect to MySql at localhost

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I am new to MySql workbench and never needed to use a lot of DBs before now.

I had an sql script containing all the DB creation, tables, population etc.
So using MySql workbench, I [Reversed Engineering Using a Create Script](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-reverse-engineer-create-script.html).
Fine, it worked as I can see my tables.

Now I want perform some select over my data and I first need to create a new connection,
So I tried to [Creating a MySQL Connection](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-getting-started-tutorial-create-connection.html)
but when I test the connection, I get the following error: "Failed to connect to MySql server on 127.0.0.1" (10061).

**Question**: what to use in the below menu (Connection/RemoteManagement/System Profile) or what else could be my problem?

[image: mySqlWorkbench]

Comment: MySQL is not sql server.

Comment: @podiluska, you are saying it because I inserted one wrong tag over 4, right? I just deleted it by the way

Comment: can you connect to that db using terminal?

Comment: @BojanKovacevic, thanks for responding. I cant connect using  mysql --host=localhost mydb because I get an error 2003, which seems to be that the server cannot be reached

Comment: sure there is: mysql -uuser -ppassword

Comment: how can I know my user/passwd, is there a default one?

Comment: usually user root, password blank (empty)

Comment: if that doesnt work,check to see if server is running (for example in services)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57265/discussion-between-eeadev-and-bojan-kovacevic).

Answer (score 0):

my problem was that I didnt have a db, so I decided to use wampserver which includes everything and it's very simple to use.